# Symfony relation with prefix

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, relation

I'm struggling with the connection/relation from the main class/table to a related class in symfony 1.4 with doctrine. The relation is

```
$relatedClass->identifier == 'e'.$mainClass->id;
```

I know that I could realise it easily without this prefix but I am working with an existing database and existing subcomponent, so I can't change this relation.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made a 'pseudo relation' like this:

```
$results = Doctrine::getTable($relatedClass)
            ->createQuery('alias')
            ->addWhere('alias.identifier=?','e'.$event->getId())
            ->execute();
```

It has several advantages:

- no changes of the existing tables necessary
- no adding of a useless column to a already huge database

It is not elegant but it is the solution with the most advantages so far.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot implement this is a relation in Doctrine because it is not a true foreign key.

If you cannot change the existing column, is it possible to create a new column? If so, write a migration to add a column to the relatedClass table with a proper foreign key relationship.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I thought about this as well but we dismissed these thoughts because of the several disadvantages.